# button with increase decrease function by one html with a number limit

Tags: html, button, input

So, i'm new to html and i would like to know how can i make a button with a increase and decrase function (-/+)

the overall should look like this

```
<button>-</button>
<input type="number"  min="0"
input type="number"  max="20">
<button>+</button>
```

(really simple example,) but the only thing i managed to get was this input

```
<input type="number"  min="0"
input type="number"  max="5">
```

aaaanndd i kinda managed to get the result bot to be longer sometime, but i just lost the command so... if someone figure it how to make it longer aand... the main task.. i will be extremely greatfull!
(the button should increase and drease by 1 and -1)

Comment: Hi please don't write stuff like "aaaanndd" this is not a messenger and it makes the post harder to read at best. Regarding your issue: There is not a default html-way to do so. You have to do it yourself. You should have a look at javascript. You can add a simple function to increase and decrease the value of the element. In your case 2 buttons and 1 input and then something like onClick="increase()".

Comment: Here you go: https://codepen.io/mtbroomell/pen/yNwwdv (not mine, but something like that should do) the arrows are there because the type is number you could also use type="text" instead to get rid of it.

Comment: Thank you! and, i'm sorry, i'm new to html and so for this website, but thank you so much for helping me out!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this by giving the input an id and targeting it from the button's onclick function (using querySelector). Then use a ternary operator to assign the value conditionally.

```html
<button onclick="document.querySelector('#steve').value=parseInt(document.querySelector('#steve').value)<1?parseInt(document.querySelector('#steve').value):parseInt(document.querySelector('#steve').value)-1"">-</button>
<input type="number" id="steve" min="0" max="20" value=0>
<button onclick="document.querySelector('#steve').value=parseInt(document.querySelector('#steve').value)>19?parseInt(document.querySelector('#steve').value):parseInt(document.querySelector('#steve').value)+1">+</button>
```

Comment: Better do the script in a different file or at least in a script tag. Looks super messy like this. Also, you repeat yourself and you do multiple `querySelector()` calls which are unnecessary since you can set a const for the element reference. There is also `document.getElementById()`. And it would probably be smart to reuse min / max values on the element.

Comment: Thank you so much! i'm trying improve my coding and this helped me a lot! Thank you!